# Why does Python 2.7 os.system(command) sometimes recurse in Windows 8 while os.startfile(command) does not recurse?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, recursion

Why does Python 2.7 `os.system(command)` sometimes recurse in Windows 8 while `os.startfile(command)` does not recurse?

My command is `backup.bat`, which is a Windows batch file.

The contents of `backup.bat` are:

```
"C:\Users\Frank Chang\Anaconda2\python.exe" -m animation_mini

@echo off
echo %time%
timeout 10 > NUL
echo %time%
```

The way I discovered that the Python 2.7 `animate` function in animation_mini.py was being invoked multiple times when `os.system`
was used is to place a print statement at the beginning of the `animate` function entry point and count the print statements in the console.

I was told today that Python 2.7 `os.system(command)` is a wrapper around the C function `execve`. But that fact does not explain the recursion I see with `os.system('backup.bat')`.

`os.system` is being called from adder.cgi, a Python 2.7 CGI script whose lines of code are:

```
#!C:\Users\Frank Chang\Anaconda2\python.exe
import cgitb
import cgi 
import os    
import signal
import threading , time
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"C:\Users\Frank Chang\Documents\Arduino\mary\data\usr\lib\python2.7\dist-packages\HTMLgen")

import HTMLgen
import subprocess
import win32api
import pandas as pd

def main(): 


    form = cgi.FieldStorage()

    numStr1 = form.getfirst("input1", "0") 
    numStr2 = form.getfirst("input2", "0") 
    numStr3 = form.getfirst("input3", "0") 
    numStr4 = form.getfirst("input4", "0") 
    numStr5 = form.getfirst("input5", "0") 
    numStr6 = form.getfirst("input6", "0") 
    numStr7 = form.getfirst("input7", "0") 

    numStr8 = form.getfirst("input8", "0") 

    numStr9 = form.getfirst("input9", "0") 

    numStr10 = form.getfirst("input10", "0") 

    numStr11 = form.getfirst("input11", "0") 

    numStr12 = form.getfirst("input12", "0") 

    numStr13 = form.getfirst("input13", "0") 

    numStr14 = form.getfirst("input14", "0") 

    from pandas import ExcelWriter

    writer = ExcelWriter('PythonExport.xlsx')

    from pandas import DataFrame

    yourdf = DataFrame({'DC Start': numStr1, 'DC Duration': numStr2, 'Plant Start': numStr3, 'Plant Duration': numStr4,
'Supplier Start': numStr5, 'Supplier Duration': numStr6}, index=[0])
    yourdf.to_excel(writer,'Disruptions')

    yourdf = DataFrame({'FGI': numStr10, 'WIP': numStr11, 'DC': numStr12, 'Plant': numStr13,
'Supplier' : numStr14}, index=[0])
    yourdf.to_excel(writer,'Policy')

    writer.save()

    os.system('backup.bat')

def processInput(numStr1, numStr2):  
    '''Process input parameters and return the final page as a string.'''
    num1 = int(numStr1) # transform input to output data
    num2 = int(numStr2)
    total = num1+num2
    return str(total)

def fileToStr(fileName): 
    """Return a string containing the contents of the named file."""
    fin = open(fileName); 
    contents = fin.read();  
    fin.close() 
    return contents

main()
```

Might my CGI script be the cause of the `os.system('backup.bat')` recursion?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "recurse" here? What's actually happening when it doesn't work the way you expect? How can you tell what it's doing?

Comment: Where are you running the `os.system` command from? Is it in the `animation_mini.py` file, or some other script? Can you show the relevant Python code (rather than the not very relevant batch script code)?

Comment: `os.system` is not a wrapper around `execve`. It calls `system`, which on Windows executes the command via `cmd.exe /c command`.

Comment: @Blckknght, I am probably using the "recurse" keyword loosely here. What I meant to say is that that the python 2.7 animate() function is being called at least 4 times in a 4 minute time span when I look at the print stream activity in the CMD windowl Looking at the Python 2.7 animation_mini.py code. I would expect that it should only be called once as is the case with os.startfile('backup.bat').

Comment: @FrancisTuan, `os.startfile` will run the batch file in a new console, which will be destroyed when the attached cmd and Python instances have exited. Do you have some kind of cmd `pause` or Python `input` statement to keep the console open to actually see whether it's getting run multiple times via `os.startfile`? If not, put a `pause` statement at the end of the batch file.

Comment: @Blckknght, os.system is being called from adder.cgi, a Python 2.7 CGI script whose first three lines of code are: def main():

Comment: Please put your code into the question itself, where you can format it properly.

Comment: @Blckknght, os.system is being called from adder.cgi, a Python 2.7 CGI script whose first several  lines of code are: def main(): form = cgi.FieldStorage(). numbervalue = form.getfirst("input1", "0") os.system('backup.bat') ; Might my CGI script be the cause of the os.system('backup.bat') recursion()?

Comment: @erkysun, I am not using CMD pause in backup.bat or Python 2.7 input in adder.cgi or animation_mini.py. I will test a cmd pause within the hour. Does Anaconda2 Python.exe -m animation_mini invoke the Python executable animation_mini.exe I built with pyinstaller?

Comment: `python.exe -m animation_mini` finds an "animation_mini" module by searching `sys.path` and runs it as the main script. It won't run a frozen `animation_mini.exe`, but you can run that instead if you want.

Comment: Adding the `pause` at the end of the batch script is just to resolve your immediate question about the apparent difference between using `os.system` and `os.startfile` to execute the batch file. It won't resolve the problem with multiple instances getting run, which is probably an issue with your CGI script.

Comment: @eryksun, How should I run a frozen animation_mini.exe in this context?

Comment: @eryksun, I added a pause at the CMD backup,bat batch file and observed that os.startfile still only ran the Python 2,7 animate function once. What is the problem with multiple instances getting run, which is probably an issue with your my script?

Comment: You would run animation_mini.exe like any other executable, e.g. on the first line of the batch file in place of `python.exe -m animation_mini`.

Comment: So you observe `os.startfile` creating a new console that has the output from running `animation_mini` followed by the echo'd time values, and finally it's waiting to continue with the message "Press any key to continue . . .". Then when you press a key, the console window closes? And no other console windows open? But when using `os.system` you see the output from running the batch file multiple times in the current console?

Comment: @eryksun, What exactly do I put on the first line of the batch file to run animation_mini.exe like any standard Python executable?

Comment: @eryksun, I observed os.startfile creating a new console that shows the output from running animation_mini.exe followed by echoed time values and finally when I press the pause key, the console window closes followed by the web browser showing Invalid system command which corresponds to error file entry , malformed header from script 'adder.cgi': Bad header: May I ask how to correct that error file entry?

Comment: @eryksun, When I use os.system I see the output from running the batch file multiple times in different new consoles each time as opposed to running the batch file multiple times in the current console.How could I fix that behavior? You mentioned earlier that the problem may be multiple instances getting run, which is an issue with the CGI script adder.cgi. Please provide more detail for this multiple instances getting run hypothesis.

Comment: @eryksun, When I put CMD /K animation_mini.exe on the first line of the windows batch file and run the adder.cgi file by redirecting the web browser to localhost:8181/adder.html and press the start button, I get the following error:C:\Apache24\htdocs>CMD /K animation_mini.exe
INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory!

Comment: @eryksun, When I put CMD /K animation_mini.exe on the first line of the windows batch file and run the adder.cgi file by redirecting the web browser to localhost:8181/adder.html and press the start button, I get the following error: INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory! which means that I lost the Anaconda2 environment variables like PYTHONPATH . How might I run animation_mini.exe with os.startfile and the windows batch file?

Comment: @eryksun, Do I need to change my Windows 8 Control Panel user permissions on C:\TMP or C:\TEMP to fix the INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory?

Comment: @eryksun, Could I ask you to look at some of the questions I asked you last night? Thank you.

Comment: @Blckknght, May I ask your advice on my unanswered questions from last night? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you've shown that would cause the batch file to be run several times. Show us more of the CGI code and maybe we can help. Where does `main()` get called from?

Comment: @Blckknght,  Sorry for the delay. I just added more of the CGI code to the original question. Could you tell me what caused the batch file to be run several times? When I put CMD /K animation_mini.exe on the first line of the windows batch file and run the adder.cgi file by redirecting the web browser to localhost:8181/adder.html and press the start button, I get the following error: INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory! which means that I lost the Anaconda2 environment variables like PYTHONPATH . How might I run animation_mini.exe with os.startfile and the windows batch file?

Comment: @Blckknght, Could I ask your advice on my last questions from today Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Both eryksun and Blckkngt had exactly the right answer yesterday about mixing multiple versions together to cause the recursive nightmare.

The solution to the INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory lies in the pyinstaller which can be corrected through using win32api.SetDllDirectory(..) and copying the parent process's environment variables and adding the key value pair "TEMP", "C:/TMP" to the dictionary

The CGI script had no bearing on whether our animation function was run several times consecutively.

Comment: @eryksun, Could I ask you to criticize this answer? Thank you.